# Error in container when connecting to mssql database

Tags: python, sql-server, docker, docker-compose

Can't connect to mssql in docker container Code piece for connecting mssql in python:

```
def connectsql():
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        "mssql+pymssql://service name")
    ms_sql_conn = engine.connect()
    df = pd.read_sql('select * from table name',
                     ms_sql_conn,
                     parse_dates=["rest_date"])
    ms_sql_conn.close()

    return df
```

or:

```
def connectsql2():
    conn = pymssql.connect(
        host=r'*******\********',
        user=r'*******',
        password=r'******',
        database='****',
    )
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select * from *********")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    print(row)
    return row
```

but i keep getting error:

> pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message
> 20009, severity 9:
> Unable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable
> or does not exist (******)')

docker-compose:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  connect:
    image: sql
    build: ./
    restart: always
```

Comment: What is the actual `host` value?  Is the application running in a container too?  If so, should it be in the `docker-compose.yml` file; if not, does the database need `ports:`?

Comment: My database is not running in a container, I used this python script before to read data from my database but now I want to move it to a container